# Which are the Error tracking tools that can be used with NetBeans 7.0?

Tags: hibernate, spring, netbeans, jakarta-ee, maven-3

I am new to enterprise Java development.. Most of the time I am busy working with Spring, Hibernate, JSF, Maven and Glassfish server 3.x.. My problem is that NetBeans sucks my mind most of the time by showing errors which are hard to debug.

Can anyone tell me which are the tools that I can use for tracking errors. Which will give me the exact line of error ? I have heard something about bugzila but not sure whether it will serve my purpose or not.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugzilla is an incident tracking tool which helps analysts, developers and QA manage incidents for a software product.  I don't think it's what you're looking for.

When you say the errors are hard to debug in Netbeans, do you mean that similar errors are easier in another IDE such as Eclipse?

If not, I think instead of looking for a tool to show you the exact line of error you need more understanding of how Java development errors are generated and reported.  Some searches on that type of understanding should produce quite a few results.

Comment: thanks for your suggetsions.... I am surely increasing my J2EE knowledge everyday... Most of my working hours are waisted just finding errors which was actually generated by some other code which is not developed by me.... Anyways thanks.